# Multi-input files for awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have two CSV files, the first one looks like below:

*File1:*

```
3124,3124,0,2,,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1106,11
6118,6118,0,0,,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,5156,51
6679,6679,0,0,,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1106,11
5249,5249,0,0,,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1106,13
2658,2658,0,0,,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1197,11
4322,4322,0,0,,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1307,13
```

*File2:*

```
7792,1307,2012-06-07,,,,
5249,4001,2016-07-02,,,,
6001,1334,2017-01-23,,,,
2658,4001,2009-02-09,,,,
9279,1326,2014-12-20,,,,
```

what I need: 
if the `$2` in *file2* = `4001`, then has to match `$1` of *file2* with *file1*,  if `$18` in *file1* = `1106` for the matched `$1` then print that line.

the expected output:

```
5249,5249,0,0,,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1106,13
```

I have tried something as the following, but with no success.

```
awk 'NR=FNR {A[$1]=$1;next} {print $1}'
```

P.S: The files are compressed, so I have to use the `zcat` command

Comment: If you are using `bash`, you can unzip the files and pass them in separately using *"process substitution"*, like this...`awk '{...}' <(zcat file1.Z) <(zcat file2.Z)`. And you need `FNR==NR{}` with double equals.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Thanks for the info, that solve the compression issue ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try something like:

```
$ cat t.awk
BEGIN { FS = "," }

# Processing first file
NR == FNR && $18 == 1106 { a[$1] = $0; next }

# Processing second file
$2 == 4001 && $1 in a { print a[$1] }


$ awk -f t.awk file1.txt file2.txt
5249,5249,0,0,,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1106,13
```